# Autosys job suspension for a specific hour in a day

Tags: job-scheduling, autosys

I need to schedule a job in Autosys in such a way that

- it runs every 20 min everyday
- it does not run for a specific time (say 01:00 to 02:00) everyday

What is the correct way to schedule this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this....

date_conditions: 1
days_of_week: all
start_mins: 00,20,40
run_window: "02:00-01:00"

Comment: Hi @Naveenkumar Can we specify multiple time limits to make sure job doesn't run on those times ? like my job should not run between 01:00 to 02:00 and 13:00 to 14:00 ?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to set up 2 jobs, with all the same parameters (except the job name, of course, which has to be unique), except one will have a run_window before the period of time you don't want it to run, and the other job will start up at the end of the time it is not to run:
Job A: run_window: 08:00-12:00
Job B: run_window: 13:00-16:00